# clearTimeout(var) not working as expected

Tags: jquery, cleartimeout

First: I searched and all questions about clearTimeout not working are about variable scope problems, not my case.

I need to auto-hide a header after X seconds without interaction, so I created two functions, `startMenuTimeout` and `clearMenuTimeout()`, this part of my code looks like that:

```
var menuTimeout = null;
function startMenuTimeout(){
  menuTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $('[auto-header]').removeClass('-visible');
  }, 2000);
}
function clearMenuTimeout(){
  clearTimeout(menuTimeout);
}
```

When the user scrolls up, I make the header visible and start the timeout, then, on `mouseenter` I clear the timeout.

Problem is, sometimes it doesn't clear the timeout, if you scroll up and down a few times, after the 2 seconds timeout, the menu goes up.

I reproduced the problem on codepen, click [here](https://codepen.io/bruno-vaz/pen/xLXYZQ?editors=1010) to access.

Comment: You're probably starting a whole lot of timeouts. The moment you create a second one with the above code, the first can't be stopped because you lose the id.

Comment: Oh I see, in that case, is there a way of creating new timeouts with the same ID, overriding the last one?

Comment: @BrunoVaz That's what timeout returns.

Comment: Yes, every call to `setTimeout` returns a new ID.

Comment: So, in theory, I could clear the timeout after setting it, then there would be only one timeout running at a time? I'll test it

Comment: Looks like it's working, thanks for the info, I'll create an answer

Comment: @BrunoVaz In the quick test I did in the JS app on my phone, the ID still seems to be incremented, even if the timeout was cleared.

Comment: Yes, it will be incremented, but only the last timeout will be active, I made quick tests here and looks like it's working.
P.s: which JS app?

Comment: @BrunoVaz JSRun. Doesn't have a window or document object, but is nice for testing quick bits of code since it has a console. I'm on Android.

Answer (score 0):

After the blazing fast comments of *Kevin B* and *Carcigenicate* I solved it.
Thing is, every time you call `setTimeout()`, it creates a new ID, then, so if you are attributing the timeout ID to a variable, it will override, losing the reference to the previous one.

The solution was clearing the timeout before setting a new one, so that only one timeout would be active at a time.

The code now looks like this:

```
var menuTimeout = null;
function startMenuTimeout(){
  clearTimeout(menuTimeout);
  menuTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $('[auto-header]').removeClass('-visible');
  }, 2000);
}
function clearMenuTimeout(){
  clearTimeout(menuTimeout);
}
```

[Click here](https://codepen.io/bruno-vaz/pen/MvEVwL?editors=1010) to access the updated pen.